# Why cant we use algorithm to find all cycles to find an hamiltonian cycle?

Tags: depth-first-search, np-complete, hamiltonian-cycle, tarjans-algorithm

I recently came across algorithms to find all cycles in an undirected graph, and was confused when i saw that they are running linear time ([example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-the-cycles-in-an-undirected-graph/)), It seem easy to use one of these to find hamilton cycle (for each cycle we find just check if it is of n nodes, e.g contains all nodes) in polynomial time, but [hamilton problem is a known NP complete problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) so i gotta be missing something... what am i missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Which of the cycles found is Hamiltonian?

Comment: @Caleth as i wrote in the original question, the ones that have all nodes (n nodes)

Comment: I'm not convinced that algorithm finds all the cycles in `O(Nodes + Edges)` time, because there can be more cycles than that. E.g. a graph where every node connects to every other node has `Nodes^2 - Nodes` edges, but `Nodes!` cycles